# How to create tabular matrix from the output of bash loop?

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I have a bashloop that looks like below:

```
for f in sorted*.bam; do
echo "Counts for positive: " $f
bedtools coverage -a my_region.bed -b $f -bed -s
echo "Counts for negative: " $f
bedtools coverage -a my_region.bed -b $f -bed -S 
done  > >(tee total_coverage_on_each_strand.txt) 2>&1
```

The output I am saving as `total_coverage_on_each_strand.txt` for $f=1 looks like this:

```
Counts for positive:  sorted1.bam
reverseKF898354 0   14580   my_region   0   +   200229  14347   14580   0.9840192
Counts for negative:  sorted1.bam
reverseKF898354 0   14580   my_region   0   +   305934  14320   14580   0.9821674
```

I was wondering if there is a way to save this in a variable instead of doing `> >(tee total_coverage_on_each_strand.txt) 2>&1`. What do I need to do in above for loop so that I could get something like below instead?

```
sample  type    counts
sorted1.bam Counts for positive 200229
sorted1.bam Counts for negative 305934
```

Comment: A first step: replace `echo "Counts for positive: " $f` with `echo -n "$f"`

Comment: Why would you write `> >(tee)` instead of `| tee`?